# add jump to page function for server-side pagination in Django

Tags: django, pagination

I have a Django project, using server-side pagination for some table.

The use want me to add a jump to function to go directly to the page he select, no matter it's a drop down or an input box.

Browse_and_adopt.html:

```
<div class="pagination">
<span class="step-links">
    {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        &emsp;<a href="?page=1">&laquo; First Page</a>
        &emsp;<a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous Page</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current">
        &emsp;Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
    </span>

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        &emsp;<a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next Page</a>
        &emsp;<a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last Page&raquo;</a>
    {% endif %}
</span>
</div>
```

view.py:

```
    @csrf_exempt
def search_book(request):
    global Title_list_cache
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        search_keyword = request.POST.get('search_keyword', '')
        print(search_keyword)


        Title_list = Title.objects.filter(Q(Format_issued="eText") | Q(Format_issued="Print"), title__icontains=search_keyword).select_related('publisher').order_by('title') | Title.objects.filter(Q(Format_issued="eText") | Q(Format_issued="Print"), author__icontains=search_keyword).select_related('publisher').order_by('title') | Title.objects.filter(Q(Format_issued="eText") | Q(Format_issued="Print"), vbid__icontains=search_keyword).select_related('publisher').order_by('title')  | Title.objects.filter(Q(Format_issued="eText") | Q(Format_issued="Print")).select_related('publisher').filter(publisher_id__name=search_keyword).order_by('title')| Title.objects.filter(Q(Format_issued="eText") | Q(Format_issued="Print"), description__icontains=search_keyword).select_related('publisher').order_by('title')

        Title_list_cache = Title_list
    else:
        Title_list = Title_list_cache

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)

    paginator = Paginator(Title_list, 10)
    try:
        Titles = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        Titles = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        Titles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    query_results_2 = Semester.objects.all()

    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page)

    query_results_code = CourseInfo.objects.none()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        username = request.user.username
    user_id = User.objects.get(username=username).id
    #user_id = 1  #test
    discipline_queryset = Discipline.objects.filter(hop1_id=user_id) | Discipline.objects.filter(hop2_id=user_id) | Discipline.objects.filter(executive_id=user_id) | Discipline.objects.filter(executive2_id=user_id) | Discipline.objects.filter(executive3_id=user_id)
    print(discipline_queryset)

    for discipline in discipline_queryset:

        id = Discipline.objects.only('id').get(name=discipline).id
        query_results_code = query_results_code | CourseInfo.objects.filter(discipline_id=id).values(
        'discipline_code', 'code').distinct().order_by('discipline_code')

    print(query_results_code)

    return render(request, 'bms/inbox/Browse_and_adopt.html', {'Titles': Titles, 'page_obj': page_obj, 'query_results_2':query_results_2, 'query_results_code':query_results_code})
```

How could I achieve that function?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the page number that you want to go into the url as parameter. Note that if the parameter passed exceeds the total number of pages, then the last page available will be served

eg:

```
#custom button to get yo specific page
<li class="page-item">
    <a href="{% url 'appname:function_name' %}?page=[page number user wants to go]">
        <span class="page-link">{{all_shop_products.number|add:"1" }}</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: how to add a input to take user input and pass  it to parameter?

Comment: anyway you want... have a form which posts the users input and redirect to the url from the views  .... or have a textbox and on onclick pass the parameter by Javascript...